# ValueErroR: rename: embedded null character indst

Tags: python

Anybody have any idea on how to fix the error?
Here is my code:

```
import os
key = "12"
path = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\test"
os.chdir(path)
for a, b, files in os.walk(path):

    for file in files:
        Encoded = ""
        filesize = os.path.getsize(file)
        if filesize > 2000000 and file.split(".")[-1] == "pdf" or file.split(".")[-1] == "docx":
            LenFileName = len(file)
            for index in range(LenFileName):
                char = file[index]
                kelid = key[index % len(key)]
                Encoded += chr(ord(char) ^ ord(kelid))
            os.rename(file,Encoded)
```

The error is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\project\python\namecoder\namecoder.py", line 16, in <module>
    os.rename(file,Encoded)
ValueError: rename: embedded null character in dst
```

Comment: What do you think that code is doing?  If your file names contain "1" or "2", your code will convert those to ASCII NUL values, and that's not valid.

Comment: OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'Network-Plus.pdf' -> '\x7fWEE^@Z\x1fa^DA\x1fBUT'

Comment: Why are you encoding the filename with XOR?

Comment: Because the project that my teacher asked

Comment: Please add the assignment to the question.

Comment: Maybe it should be `key = [1, 2]`?

Comment: He gave me a task to encrypt the contents of the file and its name with xor

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what do you think are the characters that are allowed in a file name on your system? (Did you try to find this out?) Did you try to check what result is in `Encoded` when you run the code? Do you see where it contains characters, that are not allowed in a file name? If you understand that the file name is not valid, then **what exactly is the question**?

Comment: Please read [ask] and note well that this is **not a discussion forum**. The kind of obfuscation (by the way, this is **not encryption**) that you do on the filename, simply cannot give you a valid file name in every case. You need to come up with a strategy that makes sure that the changed file names are valid. We cannot do this for you, because there are countless possible ways to do it, and no way for us to choose between them. We don't design program features here.

Comment: Everything is fine only when os.rename

Comment: No, everything is NOT fine.  Your encoding produces strings that are not legal file names.  There is no "fix".  Your algorithm is flawed.